# How to Safely call an promise-based AngularJS service in a loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am calling my Angular service as follows:

```
$scope.testData.length = 10;
for (var k = 0; k <= $scope.testData.length; k++) { 
    myTestService.saveData({
        Id: $scope.id,
        Description: $scope.jobdescrtiption,
        FirstName: $scope.firstname,
        LastName: $scope.lastname,
        Address: $scope.address,
        Phone: $scope.phone,
        Email: $scope.email                 
    }).then(function (result) {
        if (!result.data.success) {
            myDialogModal(result.data.errorMsg, 'Save error', 'OK', false)
                .result.then(function () {
                    $scope.validationdisabled = false;
                });
        } else {
            $scope.displayMessages('save', true);
        }
    });
}
```

Is this the correct way? What will happen to the promise of the first call? Also if the call for all is unsuccessful, it will display 10 popups with errors. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered moving from promises to async/await? It will simplify your script and help the readability of your code. Simply put: you await for a method on the service and, after gettting the response, you continue with the next action.

Comment: No I haven't but will have a look. I assume there is documentation I can read on angular site. But wil there be documentation for angularjs 1.x  ?

Comment: async/await is a native javascript feature which was introduced with ES2017 (ES8). To use it, you should ensure the javascript version of your angular app ponits to ES8 or higher.

Comment: @MiquelCanal The ES6 promises from async/await are not integrated with the AngularJS framework. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code as written will call the service 10 times with the same data. What is the point to that?

Comment: it also depends on what do you want to achieve. one popup with 10 error messages? one popup with one error messages but only if all requests failed? one popup with one error message if any request failed? would you prefer running requests in parallel for lower reaction time?

Comment: good point , the code should have been Id: $scope.id,
        Description: $scope.$scope.testData[k].obdescrtiption,
        FirstName: $scope.testData[k].firstname,
        LastName: $scope.testData[k].lastname,
        Address: $scope.testData[k].address,
        Phone: $scope.testData[k].phone,
        Email: $scope.testData[k].email       I have used the $q.all which combines the  promises into one and will only be resolved when all the    promises are resolved. That is the solution I have used.